# Binding method to button in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this console application which I now want to make into a WPF application. I'm new to WPF, so I'm not sure where to go from here. I currently have the following function to start a server:

```
 public static void StartListening(string[] prefixes)
    {
        HttpListener listener = new HttpListener();

        if (prefixes == null || prefixes.Length == 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("prefixes");

        foreach (string s in prefixes)
        {
            listener.Prefixes.Add("http://" + s + "/");
        }
        listener.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("\nListening...");

        listener.BeginGetContext(new AsyncCallback(OnRequest), listener);
    }
```

Now I want to be able to do this in WPF with the click of a button. I already have the following in my MainWindow.xaml.cs but I could use a hint of how to bind the StartServerButton_Click to my StartListening() method. I've been looking at using ICommand but it just seems like an overly complicated solution to this fairly simple problem.

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            IPAddress[] addrs = Array.FindAll(Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).AddressList,
               a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
            ServerOutputTextBox.AppendText("Your IPv4 address is: ");
            foreach (IPAddress addr in addrs)
            {
                ServerOutputTextBox.AppendText(addr.ToString());
            }

            //Automatically set the IP address
            string[] ips = addrs.Select(ip => ip.ToString()).ToArray();
            Response.StartListening(ips);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
        }

    }


    private void StartServerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Comment: Not much WPFish way. You may have a model (your server or better a _view_ of it) and commands to interact with it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your code, after the window is loaded, IPs are not changed. So make ips private and use it in the button click handler:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window {
private string[] ips;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    try
    {
        IPAddress[] addrs = Array.FindAll(Dns.GetHostEntry(string.Empty).AddressList,
           a => a.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork);
        ServerOutputTextBox.AppendText("Your IPv4 address is: ");
        foreach (IPAddress addr in addrs)
        {
            ServerOutputTextBox.AppendText(addr.ToString());
        }

        //Automatically set the IP address
        ips = addrs.Select(ip => ip.ToString()).ToArray();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
    }

}


private void StartServerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     Response.StartListening(ips);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Both answers so far show you how to use the code-behind click event to start your method, however since your title asks about *binding* the `Button.Command` property to your `DataContext`, I figured I'd post an answer on how to do that.

You do need an `ICommand` value in order to bind `Button.Command`. Furthermore, for binding purposes you typically want what is called a `RelayCommand` or `DelegateCommand`, which is just a fancy way of saying a command that is able to point to some unrelated code somewhere else to execute.

If you're using a 3rd party framework like Microsoft PRISM or MVVM Light, they both have a class specifically for this already, or you can create your own version of a `RelayCommand` for use with bindings.

Here's the class for a `RelayCommand` that I usually use when I don't want to use 3rd party libraries:

```
/// <summary>
/// A command whose sole purpose is to relay its functionality to other
/// objects by invoking delegates. The default return value for the
/// CanExecute method is 'true'.
/// </summary>
public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<object> _execute;
    readonly Predicate<object> _canExecute;

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command that can always execute.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute)
        : this(execute, null)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates a new command.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="execute">The execution logic.</param>
    /// <param name="canExecute">The execution status logic.</param>
    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Predicate<object> canExecute)
    {
        if (execute == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("execute");

        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    #region ICommand Members

    [DebuggerStepThrough]
    public bool CanExecute(object parameters)
    {
        return _canExecute == null ? true : _canExecute(parameters);
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
    {
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
    }

    public void Execute(object parameters)
    {
        _execute(parameters);
    }

    #endregion // ICommand Members
}
```

Your `DataContext` class would then expose an instance of this RelayCommand that goes to your method for binding purposes, like this

```
public ICommand StartServerCommand
{
    get
    {
        // If command hasn't been created yet, create it
        if (_startServerCommand == null)
        {
            _startServerCommand = new RelayCommand(
                param => StartServer()
            );
        }
        return _startServerCommand;
    }
}

private void StartServer()
{
    var ips = GetIpAddresses();
    Response.StartListening(ips);
}
```

Now that said, from the code example you've given so far you don't look like you are taking advantage of WPF's binding system correctly, so this solution may not be for you and it might be simpler to just go with an OnClick method like others have shown.

In an ideal world, your data and business logic would all exist in classes unrelated to the UI which are used as the `DataContext` behind your UI components, and you'd use bindings to pull data from your data class for display in the UI.

If you're looking to learn more about how to use WPF properly, I have some beginners articles on my blog that may help you:

- [What is this "DataContext" you speak of?](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2012/07/14/what-is-this-datacontext-you-speak-of/)
- [A Simple MVVM Example](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure if I got your question correct. But is this what you're looking for?

Xaml:

```
<Button Click=StartServerButton_Click/>
```

Code behind:

```
private void StartServerButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: That's right. I already have the <Button Click=StartServerButton_Click/> in my Xaml. I should have stated that of course. Binding button isn't really the problem, but using the StartListening() method is. I'm not sure how I can call it from my button.

Comment: Oh, allrighty then. Then I'd suggest you check out Rachel's answer since it seems like a stellar example on how to do it correctly.